# change page with function

Tags: jquery-mobile

Im new to Javascript and HTML.
I can't find what I am doing wrong, my objective is:

From a dummy login page, I click on the login button and It takes me to a page where It loads comic books from themoviedb API.

The problem Is that It won't change to the comic books page:

Here is the working code: [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/claire89/yTt9b/374/)

Code in question:

```
function goToListView() {
$(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#listMenuPage', {
    transition: 'pop',
    changeHash: false,
    reverse: true,
    showLoadMsg: true
});
```

}

Comment: I read that as of jQuery Mobile 1.4, $.mobile.changePage() is deprecated and replaced with:

$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "target", { options });

Comment: Ahh, I haven't really used jQuery mobile all that much, please disregard my previous comment. I've deleted it.

Comment: Dont use _inline_ JS, add listeners. Use `a` instead of `button`. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/yTt9b/381/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of inline code on your button, move it into the pagecreate of the login page:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#loginPage", function(){
    $("#btnLogin").on("click", function(){
        goToListView();
        return false;
    });
});
```

> Here is your updated (and simplified) **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/yTt9b/382/)**

Note: in the fiddle I set the code to "`No Wrap - in <body>`"

Answer (score 0):

```
function goToListView() {
    $.mobile.changePage('#listMenuPage');
   }
```

**PS :** dont try it in jsfiddle try it in your html file becouse somehow jsfiddle donest recognise the function

Comment: It has a strange behaviour now, when I click on the login button, the comic book page appears for a sec and them It returns to the login page :(

Comment: i will see about it ,please wait

Comment: Someone gave you a -1 so I reset It for ya with my +1 :)